# why is this Oracle query invalid

Tags: sql, oracle

```
with table1 as(select sname, sailors.sid, bid from sailors inner join reserves on sailors.sid=reserves.sid
)
table2 as(select k.sname as nam, k.sid as s1, k.bid as b1, j.sid as s2, j.bid as b2 from table1 as k join table1 as j
)
select nam from table2 where s1=s2 and b1!=b2;
```

I have also tried adding "," before creating the new table 2.  But both of the query are invalid. can someone give me the reason.

Comment: You're missing a comma after your first CTE, and what are you joining on within your 2nd CTE? Not that it's wrong, per se, but questionable.

Answer (score 1):

It is invalid because

- comma is missing
- table aliases in Oracle don't allow the `as` keyword

So:

```
with 
table1 as
  (select sname, sailors.sid, bid 
   from sailors inner join reserves on sailors.sid = reserves.sid
  ),
table2 as
  (select k.sname as nam, k.sid as s1, k.bid as b1, j.sid as s2, j.bid as b2 
   from table1 k join table1 j
  )
select nam 
from table2 
where s1 = s2 
  and b1 != b2;
```

---

I'd suggest you to always use table aliases; in `table1`, it is unclear which table contains `sname` and `bid` columns. Aliases also make query easier to read (just like you did in `table2`, which is *better* than `table1` from my point of view).